# Is it posible to change color every icon of Font Awesome in the css file?

Tags: css, colors

My page uses a lot of Font Awesome icons and they are all blue. However I would like to change them all to red to fit the sites theme. How do you go about doing this?

The css file looks like this:

```
font-face {
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-    
 webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome- webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome- webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

I have tried the color attribute but this doesnt have any effect.

Comment: "colour" ? Try the American "color" instead.

Comment: Sorry I wrote that wrong I have tried the American spelling

Comment: can you put your HTML code into your question. or a url where I can see the actual problem?

Comment: No, don't give the URL, we're not a debugging service.

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome "icons" are characters. Their colour is usually set up depending on the use, not in the Font Awesome css file.

Find where the icon is inserted in your page. The element probably holds a class or id, and then add a CSS rule in the relevant CSS file:

```
#relevant-id {
    color: red;
}
```

Or better: find where the existing blue is defined, so you'll avoid rule selectivity problems. You can learn that using [the developer tools of your browser](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#dom-and-styles).

Comment: Thanks I have tried doing this with each class as well as trying to do it for the universal css file but still no change.

Comment: @DamienDunne Look in the developer tools to see why the icons are currently blue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add a new rule in the relevant CSS file

```
.fa{
color: red !important;
}
```